Chat Considered Harmful
Could we just not use the Chat feature? If things get that out of hand then TILT - Game Over - put in a new quarter and start again. I don't see a point in embalming bad discussions in little boxes that most likely won't get looked at, except by people trying to scrape personally identifiable information about users.

Chat is designed to be a pain — get used to it. The real semantics of chat (AIUI) is: You are unwelcome here. But we (SE) prioritize politeness over honesty too much to be able to say so directly. So we invent features like chat whose intentional painful usability can make it clear without us needing to speak problematic truths.   For more background see

More technically: Could we just not use the chat feature? is just not an option.: At any random point of time a comment thread will automagically become a chat thread, You have no say in that process. And thereafter even deleting your own comments can be done by others but not you. Thats the design

Is this a venting session? :D I've found that the quality of the chat depends on the quality of the conversant. There are a number of people who have made me question my beliefs forcing me to re-evaluate my thinking and that wouldn't have come with extended discussion. I've also learned a lot about some people who have a demonstrable lack of self-insight. Such people have a fantastic gift for talking in circles and not coming to a conclusion that their logic is circular. Lastly, the chat sessions do allow for extended feedback on posts. While such exchanges do not happen often, they are an opportunity for those who genuinely seek dialog to receive it. There are without a doubt limits to the medium itself, and the more sophisticated the ideas involved, the tougher it becomes to use a mere chat session to convey the complexity and sophistication of thought. this is, I believe, doubly a potent problem for philosophical discourse, for unlike mathematics or software development, natural language conveys a robustness of meaning and nuance that doesn't distill down to an artificial language. After 5 years of participation, I've certainly seen the range of possibility the technology offers, and a variety of psychologies that are at play in discourse. Ultimately, most contributors who come in motivated eventually figure out what they want out of the site, and that often starts out as wanting to be more argumentative and gradually that impulse waning and keeping contributions confined to the Q&A format. If it's of any value, I appreciate your thoughtful humor, and believe that if no one ever used the comments for anything, the quality of answers would suffer, and the sense of community that this site brings, whatever it's value to the diversity of contributors involved, is better off with a little back and forth. :D

Thank you, I do see the sense of community, and often there are nice interactions. Chat is probably the only thing I think is less optimal.
